# Django ORM query on fk set

Tags: django, orm, relational-database

I have a problem with lookup that looks for a value in related set.

```
class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_lentgh=64)

class Availability(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    closed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room)
```

Considering that there is one availability for every date in a year. How can use ORM query to find whether room withing given daterange (i.e. 7 days) has:

1. availability exist for every day within given daterange
2. none of the availabilities has closed=True

I was unable to find any orm examples that check whether all objects within daterange exist

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate over the `date`s, and ensure that it has for that `date` an `Availability` with `closed=False`:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

rooms = Room.objects.all()
start_date = date(2022, 7, 21)  # first day
for dd in range(7):             # number of days
    dt = start_date + timedelta(days=dd)
    rooms = rooms.filter(availability__date=dt, availability__closed=False)
```

The `rooms` will after the `for` loop have a `QuerySet` with all `Room`s that have for all `date`s in that range `Availability` objects with `closed=False`.

Comment: thanks! but is it possible to do it in single orm query without reverting to raw sql?

Comment: @Kihaf: this will make a *single* SQL query: querysets are lazy. The filters are *not* performed incrementally, it simply builds up a query that will then evaluated once if you "consume" `rooms`.